# ubuntu system time

Tags: windows, time

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and Win8.1 on my computer and I have set the time zones correctly and sync the system time with internet for both OS. However, when I switch between these two OS, the system time are always incorrect. Can anyone solve the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Zhang Yifan first of all you need to check your BIOS time whether is Correct or not, Then if you need to set the timezone in Ubuntu Follow this Step and it's Works for me..
[Setting time Zone](http://www.linuxmental.com/blog/2013/11/13/setting-time-zone-in-ubuntudebian-based-servers/)

Comment: thx :)  i have checked my BIOS time and then start Ubuntu. The time is correct, however, when I reboot and start Windows, the time is incorrect again.

Comment: Have to set the timezone as shown in above ?

Comment: my time zones for both OS are correct